# Como utilizar plugin propio en ionic

Tags: ionic, plugin, npm

Estoy intentando utilizar un socket conectado por TCP en mi aplicación de Ionic 3.

Para hacer esto sigo los siguientes pasos:

1- Creo una aplicación ionic:

> ionic start pruebaTcp blank --cordova

2- Entro al directorio de la aplicación

> cd pruebaTcp

3- Instalo ionic-native (al crear el proyecto creo que ya lo incluye pero aún así lo instalo otra vez)

> npm install ionic-native --save

4- Descargo el siguiente plugin para instalarlo desde local en vez de instalarlo desde el repositorio, el plugin descargado es el siguiente: https://github.com/KoenLav/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp

5- Instalo el plugin en mi aplicación:

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp-master

Hasta aquí va todo bien, si miro los plugin que tengo instalados con el siguiente comando: `ionic cordova plugin ls` me dice que tengo instalado el plugin "cordova-plugin-..." que es el que acabo de instalar.

El problema viene a la hora de utilizar dicho plugin, a la hora de crear un socket y conectar a un host.

¿Cómo utilizo este plugin? ¿Tengo que hacer un import en el fichero home.ts? ¿Cómo sería este import?

Al ser un plugin propio no veo como hacerlo y no encuentro documentación.

He probado con la herramienta `plugman` pero ni siquiera me deja instalar el plugin.

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo de código en el propio fuente del plugin: https://github.com/KoenLav/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp/blob/master/tests/tests.js y también una api: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp es un poco rudimentario, pero puede valer para intentarlo

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta en sí y quizás porque no estoy entendiendo bien, pero ¿el paso 4 es necesario? Parecería que el paso 5 descargará e instalará el plugin desde el repositorio. ¿Cómo instalas manualmente el plugin?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Tengo que instalar el plugin desde local porque me dio problemas intentando instalarlo directamente desde la url así que lo descargué y lo instalé. Para instalarlo manualmente simplemente es el paso 5, lo pongo así porque lo tengo en la raíz del proyecto.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @track3r pero mi problema es que en ningún sitio pone donde incluir ese código. Como pongo en mi pregunta, dónde tengo que poner ese código? No encuentro ninguna guia de donde poner el código

Comment: Pues sin ver tu código de tu app no sabría decirte, pero como te decía, en el ejemplo de github, tienes un ejemplo completo, por lo que si copias y pegas y lo enlazas a tu proyecto, debería funcionar. En cualquier caso, tu pregunta no tiene nada que ver con el plugin, más bien necesitas una guía de como programar en ionic/cordova

Comment: no, el problema es no saber utilizar el plugin. Mi app lo único que hace es intentar conectar un socket por tcp a mi servidor. Como he dicho antes, un trozo de código por norma general no soluciona mucho si no se explica más, ni como utilizarlo, ni donde aplicarlo ni nada. Es más, en esta página no se considera una buena respuesta el pegar un trozo de código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes acceso a el desde cualquier componente de la aplicación a través del objecto windows

```
ngOnInit() {
    (<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, () => {
        console.log('funcionado!');
    });
}
```

Comment: lo pruebo a ver =), gracias

Comment: Ya está funcionando con una sola diferencia, lo tengo que llamar así: (<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcp.create... pero perfecto, muchas gracias.